# phppgadmin page works on server but not from LAN

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed PHPpgAdmin in ubuntu.

If i use http://localhost/phppgadmin then it works if i am at the server

But if i use from LAN

```
Http://ip -- works
Http://ip/phppgadmin-- don't work
```

It says permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of the site, due to the nature of the script, I would be 99% sure it comes shipped with some sort of IP based restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, edit the file `/etc/phppgadmin/apache.conf`. You will see lines that look like this:

```
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128 192.168.0.0/24
```

Add an additional line that allows access from your subnet. Then make Apache re-load its configuration.

*Simply add an entry for your subnet (here: all machines with IPs in 192.168.0.XXX) in the given **allow from** line*

Answer (score 0):

Nate gives usefull advice, but I don't think that'll help you. As the local IP's usually range inside 192.168.*.*, which is already inside the range 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0.

My advice to you, is to temporarily change the line

> deny from all

to

> allow from all

Inside **/ect/phppgadmin/apache.conf** And see if it changes anything (please not that I am not sure of this path. I am a Windows user myself.). It would be wise to edit your question with the results of this, so you can be helped further.

Also, have you tried to reach it from a different computer/device in your network, or just one?